# How to load a new view upon orientation change - iOS SDK xcode Interface builder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, sdk, orientation

So I am developing this view based app and I have an app that I want to start in landscape mode (haven't quite worked out how to do that, because in the plist file the "initial device orientation" isn't an option as I am assuming it used to be, from what people have said (I'm new to this app developing thing)).

Anyway I want to switch to a completely new view when I rotate to Portrait, and also a another new view when I rotate to portrait upside down. Up to now I have added View2Viewcontroller.(h+m) into my classes and also View2.xib into my resources.

I have this code:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
  if((fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||
     (fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))
  {    
    // Load the view controller I want to display in portrait mode...
  }

}
```

But I'm not too sure how to load the view controller or even where to put this code.

Comment: Exact duplicate (same user): [How to load a new view upon orientation change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752777/how-to-load-a-new-view-upon-orientation-change)

Comment: You need a parent view controller that switches which child view controller is displayed, depending on the device orientation.

Answer (score 0):

I advise to you use .nibv files, it's better to understand how to initilize view in by code.
anyway there is what you need.

```
 [[viewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

in code you can do the same without nib filesw by this code

```
  CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

//create a full-screen window
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

    //create our view controller and add its view to the window
    viewController = [ViewController new];
    [window addSubview:[viewController view]];
    [window makeKeyandVisible];
```